# Execute application through custom URI in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

**Update:** By adding ":" next to app3 when calling it I no longer get the error, however the app is still not launched, instead I get an error message telling me I need a new application to open app3, how can I solve this? Why can't I simply open the app?

I've got an applicacion `app3` that doens't do anything other than just opening a blank page. [image: <code>app3</code>]

From another application `app4` I'm trying to call `app3`

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        callUri();

    }

    private async void callUri()
    {
        var uriBing = new Uri(@"app3");

        // Launch the URI
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);
    }
```

But am getting the folling error message:

`System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'`

What exactly am I doing wrong? The Windows documentation for URI handling doens't really how how to call custom URI, only their premade ones, and I haven't seen any other questions regarding this. The App3 packages have already been created.

Comment: I've never worked with UWP before. Just just taking a random guess: `app3` isn't a valid URI. You'd probably need to provide more, perhaps something like `app3:` so it knows that app3 is the schema.

Comment: @mason Yes, that worked. However after that the app is still not working, as it now says I need a new application to open it.

Comment: Sounds like a different question to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your application to be launched using a protocol (it's called a protocol i.e: yourappname://), you need to define it in the appxmanifest declaration. Just like what you did in your app. Then you can call it using your app name and a colon (app://)

Now your app won't go to your default page once it's launched via protocol, you'll just see a blank page. You need to handle it in the OnActivated method in App.xaml.cs, you need to override that method and handle the protocol activation.

```
  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
      {
         ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
         // Navigate to a view 
         Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
         if (rootFrame == null)
         {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
         }
         // assuming you wanna go to MainPage when activated via protocol
         rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs); 

      }
   }
```

For more info you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

Comment: I still get prompted to find an app capable of opening app3 in the Windows Store

Comment: are you doing it with a colon and slash, try to ad two slashes(app://).  Another reason why you can be prompted with app selection dialog is that there is another app that was registered with the same protocol. If that's the case it will prompt you to select an app to open and you should see your app3 in the list.

Comment: Even with two slashes I get prompted to sekect an app from the Windows Store, the list of recommended apps to open app3 is also empty.

Comment: Have you tried deploying app3? You need to deploy app3 in order for it to be registered in the OS. If you are working on a single solution with 2 projects (app3 & app4), try to right click on the solution. And in configuration manager, select multiple start up and make sure that you start app3 before you start app4. It will then initially run both apps. You can close app3 and you can try to launch it via app4.

Comment: There is no need for the double-slash for simple schemes. The [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) calls out when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if your protocol name in appmanifest\declarations is **app3**, your customized Url was supposed to be app3://. After deployed app3, you can launch it by LaunchUriAync.

e.g

```
await LaunchUriAsync(@"app3://")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation